# Scroll to highlighted word in Text

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to scroll to a selected/highlighted word inside a `Text`.

[image: highlighted text]

```
@Composable
fun AutoScrollText(
    text: String = LoremIpsum(1000).values.first()
) {
    val words = remember {
        Regex("(\\w+)").findAll(text)
    }
    var currentWordIndex by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    val currentWord = words.elementAt(currentWordIndex)

    Log.d("TEST RECOMPOSITION", "$currentWordIndex ${currentWord.value}")

    // Increment current word index
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = null){
        while (true) {
            currentWordIndex = minOf(currentWordIndex + 1, words.count() - 1)
            // SCROLL HERE

            delay(1000)
        }
    }

    // inefficient to recreate the entire annotated string?
    val annotatedText = buildAnnotatedString {
        append(text)
        addStyle(
            SpanStyle(background = Color.Yellow),
            start = currentWord.range.first,
            end = currentWord.range.last + 1
        )
    }

    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    Text(
        text = annotatedText,
        modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState),
    )
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun AutoScrollTextPreview() {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        AutoScrollText()
    }
}
```

If the text is large enough to be scrollable, would it be better to split by `\n` and use a `LazyColumn`? Also, does changing the selected word and creating a new annotated string cause the entire Text to be recreated (without reusing previous computations)?

Answer (score 0):

You could scroll directly in `onTextLayout`, which is called each time the `annotatedText` (highlighted word) changes.

```
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Text(
        text = annotatedText,
        modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState),
        onTextLayout = {
            val line = it.getLineForOffset(currentWord.range.first)
            val top = it.getLineTop(line)
            Log.d("TEST LAYOUT", "$line $top ${currentWord.value}")

            scope.launch {
                scrollState.animateScrollTo(top.toInt())
            }
        }
    )
```

I tried increasing the number of words and decreasing the `delay` and got messages such as:

```
14:09:34.574  I  Skipped 93 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
14:09:36.148  E  >>> msg's executing time is too long
14:09:36.148  E  Blocked msg = { when=-1s560ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1 } , cost  = 1560 ms
14:09:36.148  E  >>>Current msg List is:
14:09:36.148  E  Current msg <1> = { when=-27d0h48m21s626ms what=1 target=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler }
14:09:36.148  E  >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
14:09:37.722  E  >>> msg's executing time is too long
14:09:37.722  E  Blocked msg = { when=-1s560ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1 } , cost  = 1560 ms
14:09:37.722  E  >>>Current msg List is:
14:09:37.722  E  Current msg <1> = { when=-27d0h48m23s200ms what=1 target=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler }
14:09:37.722  E  >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
14:09:39.293  E  >>> msg's executing time is too long
14:09:39.293  E  Blocked msg = { when=-1s561ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1 } , cost  = 1560 ms
14:09:39.293  E  >>>Current msg List is:
14:09:39.293  E  >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
14:09:39.293  I  Skipped 93 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
14:09:40.867  E  >>> msg's executing time is too long
```

(for `LoremIpsum(10000)` and `delay(10)`)

This makes me think that the `Text` redoes the layout computations from scratch when given a new annotated string.